# Is it possible to set and reuse variables in the kdb select statement?

Tags: kdb

I would like to define some variables in my select statement. For example, here I want to define bid, ask as a modified value of the original value stored in the table (this code won't work):

```
select ts,ticker,bid:(bid1_price*1e-4),ask:(sl1_price*1e-4),wt:((next ts) - ts),spread:(ask - bid),wtspread:(((next ts) - ts) wavg (ask - bid)) from md where...
```

How can I define variables in the select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your bid and ask columns first, then use them in the update...

```
update wt:((next ts) - ts), spread:(ask - bid), wtspread:(((next ts) - ts) wavg (ask - bid)) by date from select ts, ticker, bid:(bid1_price*1e-4), ask:(sl1_price*1e-4) from md where...
```

Comment: This database has multiple dates. One difference I noticed when I run your query is that the wt field for the last record of each date is populated with the difference in time-stamps across two consecutive dates, while in my original query it's set to null.

Comment: Edited - not sure why mine gave different results, but the new one should work

Comment: Perfect. So kdb runs aggregate verbs by date in a select statement by default (I didn't use any by date clause in my original select), while using the update instruction does not. I guess update is implemented differently?

Comment: Not exactly - looks like Kdb doesn't do the "next" across partitions. If I do `select ((next ts)-ts) from select from md...` I get a similar result to the update.